# Python - transform string into a table using rsplit for each line

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and need some help with a string I have that looks like this:

```
string='Starters\nSalad with Greens 14.00\nSalad Goat Cheese 12.75\nMains\nPizza 12.75\nPasta 12.75\n'
```

and need to transform it into a table that looks more like this:

```
Category   Dish   Price
Starters   Salad with Greens   14.00
Starters   Salad Goat Cheese   12.75
Mains   Pizza   12.75
Mains  Pasta  12.75
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I was trying to apply string.rsplit(" ",2) but couldn't figure out to make it do it per line. And had no idea how to repeat the headers into a separate column.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does this string come from? Seems like an X/Y problem.

Comment: It's ambiguous how you want to treat categories since they do not appear with each dish.. Do you want to assume all entries are Startes until Mains appear?

Comment: My assumption is you are creating this string. Instead of this string you should be storing this value in `list`. Then you may format the table using `tabulate`  library. Check this [How to create a table in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730963/how-to-create-a-table-in-python/35731012#35731012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I would use it in a production environment but for the sake of academic challenge:

```
import re

string = """Starters
Salad with Greens 14.00
Salad Goat Cheese 12.75
Mains
Pizza 12.75
Pasta 12.75"""

rx = re.compile(r'^(Starters|Mains)', re.MULTILINE)

result = "\n".join(["{}\t{}".format(category, line)
                for parts in [[part.strip() for part in rx.split(string) if part]]
                for category, dish in zip(parts[0::2], parts[1::2])
                for line in dish.split("\n")])
print(result)
```

This yields

```
Starters    Salad with Greens 14.00
Starters    Salad Goat Cheese 12.75
Mains   Pizza 12.75
Mains   Pasta 12.75
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you *have to* decide how to differentiate category and item. I think that an item should have its price. This code checks if a dot is present, but you probably should use regexp.

```
s = 'Starters\nSalad with Greens 14.00\nSalad Goat Cheese 12.75\nMains\nPizza 12.75\nPasta 12.75'
items = s.split('\n')
# ['Starters', 'Salad with Greens 14.00', 'Salad Goat Cheese 12.75', 'Mains', 'Pizza 12.75', 'Pasta 12.75']

category = ''
menu = {}
for item in items:
    print(item)
    if '.' in item:
        menu[category].append(item)
    else:
        category = item
        menu[category] = []
print(menu)

# {'Starters': ['Salad with Greens 14.00', 'Salad Goat Cheese 12.75'], 'Mains': ['Pizza 12.75', 'Pasta 12.75']}
```

UPD: You may replace

```
if '.' in item:
```

with

```
if re.match(r".*\d.\d\d", item):
```

It is searching for strings which end like 1.11 (it is useful if you have abbreviations in category name)

Comment: You can also check if it `isalpha`. If not, there are prices

Answer (score 0):

try this. Note: it's assuming 'Starters' are listed before 'Mains'

```
category = 'Starters'
for item in string.split('\n'):
    if item == 'Mains': category = 'Mains'
    if item in ('Starters', 'Mains'): continue

    price = item.split(' ')[-1]
    dish = ' '.join(item.split(' ')[:-1])
    print ('{} {} {}'.format(category, dish, price))
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was trying to achieve!

Comment: This is not the best answer, as you should change the code if you include a dessert. @Diman answer is more general. imho

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class-based solution in Python3 with operator overloading to gain additional accessibility over the data:

```
import re
import itertools
class MealPlan:
    def __init__(self, string, headers):
       self.headers = headers
       self.grouped_data = [d for c, d in [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(string.split('\n'), key=lambda x:x in ['Starters', 'Mains'])]]
       self.final_grouped_data = list(map(lambda x:[x[0][0], x[-1]], [grouped_data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(grouped_data), 2)]))
       self.final_data = [[[a, *list(filter(None, re.split('\s(?=\d)', i)))] for i in b] for a, b in final_grouped_data]
       self.final_data = [list(filter(lambda x:len(x) > 1, i)) for i in self.final_data]
    def __getattr__(self, column):
        if column not in self.headers:
            raise KeyError("'{}' not found".format(column))
        transposed = [dict(zip(self.headers, i)) for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.final_data)]
        yield from map(lambda x:x[column], transposed)
    def __getitem__(self, row):
         new_grouped_data = {a:dict(zip(self.headers[1:], zip(*[i[1:] for i in list(b)]))) for a, b in itertools.groupby(list(itertools.chain(*self.final_data)), key=lambda x:x[0])}
         return new_grouped_data[row]
    def __repr__(self):
         return ' '.join(self.headers)+'\n'+'\n'.join('\n'.join(' '.join(c) for c in i) for i in self.final_data)

string='Starters\nSalad with Greens 14.00\nSalad Goat Cheese 12.75\nMains\nPizza 12.75\nPasta 12.75\n' 
meal = MealPlan(string, ['Category', 'Dish', 'Price'])
print(meal)
print([i for i in meal.Category])
print(meal['Starters'])
```

Output:

```
Category Dish Price
Starters Salad with Greens 14.00
Starters Salad Goat Cheese 12.75
Mains Pizza 12.75
Mains Pasta 12.75
['Starters', 'Starters', 'Mains', 'Mains']
{'Dish': ('Salad with Greens', 'Salad Goat Cheese'), 'Price': ('14.00', '12.75')}
```